# How do I export this model so that it is is one object using one material?

Tags: materials, uv, shaders, export, point-clouds

[image]

I downloaded this model from SketchFab

https://skfb.ly/oLsvy

and I want to turn it into a point cloud. However the way I usually do this is by assigning a material with a single image texture on one UV Map (As Shown in the Node tree image).

[image]

The model I have is too complicated to do this as it has Multiple Textures, UV Maps etc. I keep watching videos online about baking multiple textures into one but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I wanted to know if there was a way for me to export the model with a single image texture on one UV Map so that I can use the same node tree I have for my point cloud effect. I basically just want to have one object with one material shader that uses one image texture on one UV Map. I thought it would be a very easy thing to do but clearly more convoluted than I thought ://